# What version of MySQL with Ruby On Rails 3.2.8?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am reading through 'Pragmatic Agile Web Dev w/ Rails 4th edition for Version 3.2' and am preparing my production environment to use Mysql. I got to the point in the book where it says:

"There are plenty of alternatives to SQLite, both free and commercial. We will go with MySQL. It is available via your native packaging tool in Linux, and an installer is provided for OS X on the MySQL website.2 We recommend that you download MySQL 5.1, as MySQL 5.5 is known not to work with Rails 3.1."

**Does anybody have experience with MySQL 5.5 and Rails 3.2.8?** I am wondering what problems the book is referring to and if they have been resolved in the current stable version 3.2.8. **Any suggestions on what version to use?**

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

No idea what the book is referring to. I have several production websites using MySQL 5.5 and Rails 3.2, no problem. Just use the gem `mysql2`.